# mkdir in configfs not permitted

Tags: permissions, linux-kernel, device-tree

On my embedded System I enabled the `CONFIG_CONFIGFS_FS=y` to have access to the configFS. When booted, I mounted it with help of `mount -t configfs none /sys/kernel/config`. That works like charm:

```
# mount | grep configfs
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
```

Now I try to create a folder `device-tree`, as I wanted to try out the dynamic loading of dtbo-files from userspace. Unfortunately I get an error:

```
# mkdir -p /sys/kernel/config/device-tree/overlays/dummy
mkdir: can't create directory '/sys/kernel/config/device-tree/': Operation not permitted
```

I already made sure that `CONFIG_OF_DYNAMIC` and `CONFIG_OF_OVERLAY` are set.

The permissions of `/sys/kernel/config` are:

```
# ls -la /sys/kernel/config/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root             0 May 31 16:57 .
drwxr-xr-x    8 root     root             0 May 31 15:56 ..
```

So I'd have guessed, that writing to this directory as `root` should not be a problem at all.

Any hints, how I could investigate that issue?

Comment: but the problem is, that i *can't* create the folders as root. At the moment I only have the `root` user on my system who already is the owner of `/sys/kernel/config` and who already has write permissions. Why should creating another user (and making it the owner) change anything here?

Comment: Now I understand the problem! From your post, I understood that `root` can create it, but you try as some other user. I'm sorry, I was on the completely wrong track.

Comment: Ah I see, sorry for making it not clear enough. I tried to make it clear through the use of `#` before the command, but maybe that was a little too subtile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was, that I used the mainline Kernel 6.1 (LTS) that does not support `CONFIG_OF_CONFIGFS`. So I downloaded a dtbo-configfs devicedriver from here: https://github.com/ikwzm/dtbocfg, compiled it and loaded it into the kernel. Then after mounting the `configfs`, I already had the `device-tree` directory available.